# Event Listeners not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my attempt to learn core JavaScript, I am now learning about EventListeners.

My problem is that in code below EventListener not being fired in IE (working just fine in Firefox and Chrome).

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

My code is:

```
<p>The first captain of the USS Enterprise NCC-1701 was
            <a id="wikipedia" href="http://en.wikipedia.org">Christopher Pike</a>.
        </p>
        
        <script type="application/javascript">
        
                var link = document.getElementById("wikipedia");
                // for firefox and other browsers
                if (typeof link.addEventListener != "undefined")
                {
                    link.addEventListener("click", clickListener, false);
                }
                // IE only
                else if (typeof link.attachEvent != "undefined")
                {
                    link.attachEvent("onclick", clickListener);
                }
                    
                function clickListener()
                {
                    var link = document.getElementById("wikipedia");
                    link.setAttribute("href", "www.example.com/");
                    open("http://www.example.com");
                    return false;
                }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that really the complete code? If so then the reference should be to 'clickListener' and not 'wikipediaLink.clickListener'.

The real issue is the attribute value "application/javascript" isnt IE friendly, change it to "text/javascript" and along with the function referencing and you should be good.

By the way, I would use an abstracted addEvent function - mine in particular fixes the 'this' keyword issue in JScript and also because of the initial assignment it doesn't need to check whether the element supports the addEventListener method or not since it checks the window object first:

```
 var addEvent = (function() {
    function addEventIE(el, ev, fn) {
        return el.attachEvent('on' + ev, function(e) {
        return fn.call(el, e);
        });
    }
    function addEventW3C(el, ev, fn) {
        return el.addEventListener(ev, fn, false);
    }
    return window.addEventListener ? addEventW3C:addEventIE;
    })();
```

Usage:

```
addEvent( link, 'click', clickListener );
```

Comment: I fixed it according to what you suguested, it is still not working under IE

Comment: Found the real issue, alter the type attribute.

Comment: I re-edited my post so incase you want to use that addEvent method as a basis for your own, or use that, it beats having to manually do those types of checks.

Comment: "addEvent()" is yet another layer. Why not simply create a function addEventListener() when it doesn't exist yet?

Creating W3C comformity is almost ever a better idea than creating yet another custom layer.

Comment: because it's not possible to completely create methods for every single DOM method that IE doesn't support - which is why we have libraries like jQuery to abstract these for us, that is if I'm understanding correctly and you're referring to overloading something like the Element.prototype? ( actually I doubt the latter is even possible in IE ).

Answer (score 0):

Try to determine the browser using this method:

```
theFunction = function() { alert("Clicked!"); };
theElement = document.getElementById('wikipedia');

// All modern browsers
if (window.addEventListener) {
    theElement.addEventListener('click', theFunction, false);

// IE
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    theElement.attachEvent('onclick', theFunction);

// Failure
} else {
    alert("Your browser is definitely too old.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i like your solution a lot.